# How to perform sorting on an array without using .sort()

Tags: swift, sorting

I am trying to find the easiest way to sort an array without using `sort()` function. I tried searching but i could not find any questions that were on SWIFT. I found several questions about php and javascript and so far nothing on swift.

```
var arr = [7,6456,2135,164,1345,4,8,5,87456,123,2,87,724,6523,1]
        var arrSorted = arr
        var index = arr.count
        repeat {
          var previousSwapIndex = 0
          
          for i in 1..<index {
            if (arrSorted[i - 1] as! Int) > (arrSorted[i] as! Int) {
               
                let prevVal = arrSorted[i - 1]
                let currentVal = arrSorted[i]
                arrSorted[i] = prevVal
                arrSorted[i - 1] = currentVal
              previousSwapIndex = i

            }
          }

          index = previousSwapIndex
          
        } while (index != 0)
        print(arrSorted as Array)
```

This method works but i am looking for something that is better than this and easier than this.
(Edit[Clarification] :- better = faster / quicker ,as this iterates 120 times before the array is sorted)
Could someone help me out?

Comment: Find the algorithm you want to perform first (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) , try to implement it, and then we'll talk. Now, don't use `NSMutableArray`, prefers Swift Array.

Comment: The "best" and "easiest" way to sort is almost definitely going to be the `sorted(by:)` method

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you can't use the standard library methods?

Comment: @Sam I have a college test tomorrow and they definitely wont allow us to use sort function.

Comment: @Larme Whichever is easiest to write. (Sometimes they wont let us use computers and we are forced to write on paper)

Comment: How large is your input going to be? If it’s small I guess below answer should work for you, else look for quickSort if  you want to run your algo with  very large inputs.

Comment: @TusharSharma If the input is small the one i posted the below one works well, but what if the input is large? Thanks for the suggestion, i will look up quickSort.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic implementation of [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) in Swift. It takes an `inout` array, but you should be able to modify it to return an array if that's what you want.

```swift
func sort<T: Comparable>(_ array: inout [T]) { 
    var i = 1 
    while i < array.count { 
        var x = array[i] 
        var j = i - 1 
        while j >= 0 && array[j] > x { 
            array[j+1] = array[j] 
            j -= 1 
        } 
        array[j+1] = x 
        i += 1 
    }
}
```

To use it:

```swift
var intArr = [1, 7, 3, 6, 4]
sort(&intArr)
print(intArr) // [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
var stringArr = ["hello", "goodbye", "a", "string", "z", "another string"]
sort(&stringArr)
print(stringArr) // ["a", "another string", "goodbye", "hello", "string", "z"]
```

It will work on any type that conforms to `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find about all the different methods of sorting from this git.

**https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club**

I checked a few and none of them are using any .sort() functions. Pick whichever feels easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var unsortedStringArray = ["B", "C", "Z", "A", "H"]
var unsortedIntArray = [7,8,3,4,5,9,1,2,6]

func sortFunction<T:Comparable>(array: [T]) -> [T]{

var unsortedArray = array
for i in 0..<unsortedArray.count {
    for j in 0..<unsortedArray.count{
        var temp: T
        if unsortedArray[i] < unsortedArray[j] {
            temp = unsortedArray[i]
            unsortedArray[i] = unsortedArray[j]
            unsortedArray[j] = temp
        }
      }
    }
   return unsortedArray
}
let resultStringArray = sortFunction(array: unsortedStringArray)
let resultIntArray = sortFunction(array: unsortedIntArray)

print(resultStringArray) //["A", "B", "C", "H", "Z"]
print(resultIntArray) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).